# cannot import .obj into blender 2.8, but works in 2.79

Tags: error

[image]

i am getting this error. i've tried multiple versions of blender 2.8 but none work.

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? It says that it can't find the file or directory.

Comment: Ya I've tried taking the .obj out of every folder and just placing it on my desktop and still can't find it

Comment: Can you try uploading the OBJ file? Blender 2.8 candidate release can open OBJ files no problem for me

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SuKy7ZHatMfOcir6rG2HINaDT1loZjjb

Comment: Thanks for sharing the file. I can confirm something goes wrong and I have to investigate this further.

Comment: Found the problem and solution, writing the answer takes a bit of time.

Comment: BTW what program did you use to save the model? Was it MeshLab?

Comment: thank you for solving this problem for me! i really appreciate it. also the program was agisoft metashape

Comment: You would also need to edit the `.mtl` where the `map_Kd` has the filename in quotes. Otherwise it won't load the texture during import.

Comment: Bastien Montagne just confirmed that this will be patched.

Comment: This is now fixed in the master branch. Not sure if this will make it into the 2.8 release, likely it'll be 2.81.

Answer (score 2):

You stumbled upon a curious problem with filename handling in the `.obj` format, that isn't well defined in the specification. I will discuss this with the Blender devs, perhaps the importer needs small adjustments to parse the file correctly under these specific circumstances. Since it worked in 2.79b it can be considered a regression.

**TL;DR** The handling for filenames with blanks isn't well defined in the `.obj` format specification and Blender expected a different format than what was provided in your file.

---

**The Problem**

The `.obj` is a [text format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/wavefrontobj/egff.htm) for storing 3D models. The format contains various attributes that describe the geometry of the model. Typically the `.obj` is accompanied by a `.mtl` which describes the material and textures applied to the model. In order to keep track which files belong together, the `.obj` may contain a `mtllib` attribute followed by the filename of the `.mtl`.

Usually the beginning of an `.obj` would look something like this:

```
# Blender v2.80 (sub 74) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib test.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
```

In case of your file it is:

```
# 
mtllib "tree stump1 original model.mtl"
usemtl tree_stump1_original_model
v 4.136163 -1.200306 -10.798826 0.113725 0.152941 0.141176
v 4.140683 -1.205297 -10.794383 0.117647 0.156863 0.145098
```

Notice that the filename contains quotations marks. This is causing the problem. The software you used to export this model quoted the filename to avoid confusion on how to interpret the filename. While this is common practice in other file formats the specification for `.obj` doesn't mention quoting filenames and says specifically:

> Blank space and blank lines can be freely added to the file to aid in formatting and readability.

Which can be interpreted as blanks in filenames can be stored as is, which is precisely what Blender does. Unfortunately Blender's importer doesn't expect the quotation marks in the filename therefore misinterpreting the correct filepath. This results in the aforementioned error in your question.

---

**The Fix**

Open the `.obj` file in a text editor of your choice an remove the quotes and save. It should look like this:

```
# 
mtllib tree stump1 original model.mtl
usemtl tree_stump1_original_model
v 4.136163 -1.200306 -10.798826 0.113725 0.152941 0.141176
```

The file can now be imported by Blender.

Comment: The ticket for this issue can be found here: https://developer.blender.org/T67266